# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, does $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ as well?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I've been learning about the Fourier transform, and when you apply to derivatives.

All of the notes I've read seem to imply that if $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0,$$ then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{df}{dx}(x)=0.$$
**Under what conditions can it be true?** It holds for obvious functions like $e^{-x}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: What about $\sin(x)/x$ as a counter example?

Comment: @user160738 that not a counterexample

Comment: @Coolwater Yes, seems not, but simple modification makes it one - I was thinking something might go wrong if it was infinitely oscillating towards $\infty$ and first thing came up was $\sin$, so I stated it without much thinking

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question linked. I also asked another question, highlighted in bold

Comment: Edited so that the remaining question is clear and not in any way a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: If $f$ has a finite limit and $f'$ has a limit then the limit of $f'$ is zero. Is this the kind of condition you have in mind?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. As I say, it appears to hold in some cases, but I see not others as the current answers show

Comment: Case closed, then?

Comment: I was kind of hoping for conditions that apply only to $f$, i.e. they don't assume anything about $f'$

Comment: Using the generalization of the oscillating examples given you can see that the oscillation rate can't be speeding up too much faster than the amplitude decay rate. If $\frac{\sin f}g$ then $f'/g\rightarrow0$ and $g'/g^2\rightarrow0$ are sufficient. Of course the condition varies depending on the exact nature of f, g, sin, & cos. If the function isn't oscillating, i.e. eventually monotone, then you get what you want, that f and f' both go to zero. You could use this idea to construct other functions

Answer (score 2):

No consider the function $ f(x) = \frac{\sin (x^4)}{x}$

Then $f'(x)= x^3 \cos (x^4) - \frac{\sin (x^4)}{x^2} $

Comment: Small typo in derivative, 2 instead of 3?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=sin(x^2)/x$.

Comment: I don't think this works. Oscillations don't speed up fast enough. Need power greater than 2 in sine, yes?